# How to read raw response on HTTPTOOLKIT?

Tags: http, http-toolkit

When I view an http response, it seems the http toolkit failed to decode the response body to json, and I've no idea how to read the response body.

```
Request Header:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.0

Response Header:
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Http Toolkit shows the error: `End of file expected.json(0)`

Here's the raw data:

```
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
```

If the response is invalid, then why can the application that received the response use it? please enlighten me, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when HTTP Toolkit validates the contents of the response body as JSON. It appears because the headers say that the content is JSON (the `content-type` header) but it's not: `594962502f4a30...` is not valid JSON. JSON would look like `{"Hello": ["world"]}` or similar.

This instead appears to be some binary data, transmitted in Base64 format.

HTTP Toolkit is showing you the correct body, with an error warning you that it doesn't match the headers. This is a mistake in the server hosting this API. It doesn't mean the app cannot read this data though: if the app already knows what content it expects, it can just ignore the content-type header and parse the data any way it likes.

To see the 'real' data, you can select the Base64 option in the dropdown showed on the response body. Unfortunately, I think that won't help you very much, as this shows a large chunk of binary data that's not easily interpretable.

To understand what this response actually means, you will need to work out the format of that data. That may require more research or reverse engineering the app itself to understand how it parses the data or look for other clues (e.g. libraries with known network protocols such as gRPC).

Comment: why are you so sure that it is base64? how do you differentiate between base32, base64 or other encodings? anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: That's a fair question! It was a "most common format" guess - in this case in fact, on closer inspection it probably is hex data, as the only letters it contains are a to f in lowercase. Decoding that leads to a string like "YIbP/J07Ey..." which almost certainly _is_ Base64 (containing A-Z a-z 0-9 + / and trailing = padding). Double decoding like that is bizarre though. And as far as I can tell, the decoded base64 doesn't immediately look like anything meaningful either unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I've now located the encryption method in the [AcakKata class](https://github.com/Reyuki-san/ugh-java/releases/tag/1.2) of the application, and I can confirm that it uses base64 strings inside encoded hex format :)